# Plot violin plot with multiple pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot, ggpattern

I want a violin plot with 4 violin, 2 with striped pattern and 2 with no pattern.

I only obtain striped pattern, can you help me please?

```
 gg <- ggplot(AdPluslong, aes(Eval, Total.Score)) +
       geom_violin_pattern(aes(fill = as.factor(TypeGroupe),
                               pattern_shape = as.factor(TypeGroupe)),
         pattern = 'stripe',
         pattern_density = 0.001,
         pattern_angle = 45,
         colour  = 'black'
       )+scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what you are looking for without having your data or a sketch of the desired output (there are 6 different ways that two out of four violins could be striped), but using the pattern alpha seems like the easiest solution to me here:

```r
ggplot(AdPluslong, aes(Eval, Total.Score)) +
  geom_violin_pattern(aes(fill = as.factor(TypeGroupe),
                          pattern_alpha = as.factor(TypeGroupe)),
                      pattern_density = 0.001,
                      pattern_angle = 45,
                      colour  = 'black') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  scale_pattern_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

There was no data included in the question, so I have inferred its approximate properties as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

set.seed(1)

AdPluslong <- data.frame(Eval = rep(c('A', 'B'), 100),
                         Total.Score = rnorm(200),
                         TypeGroupe = rep(1:2, each = 100))
```